# Remote only: could not load type Azure.AzureNamedKeyCredential from assembly Azure.Core

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, typeloadexception

I am experiencing issues with the azure function app that gets triggered via azure service bus. The issue happens only in the cloud. Local execution is fine & messages are processed as expected.

When deployed to the azure cloud it throws `System.TypeLoadException` before starting the listening operation. Hence none of the messages gets processed.

The error message reads "`The listener for function '{{FunctionName}}' was unable to start. Could not load type 'Azure.AzureNamedKeyCredential' from assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'`"

Any idea why I don't see this error when running locally but happens only in the remote?

Comment: https://www.koskila.net/fixing-not-load-file-assembly-one-dependencies-error/

Comment: Hi @Kishor, it's hard to say what's going on, but my best guess is that you're reading the key you're passing to the AzureNamedKeyCredential from a local.settings.json file that doesn't exist in the server. I would recommend you to study the following topics: "Azure Variable Group" and "Azure Key Vault". If this is it, first set it up directly in the Azure Variable Group (insecure) and if it works, set it in the Key Vault (secure) and then use that Key Vault secret in the Variable Group (option: link secrets).